# Undefined method "to_liquid" in mailing, but not in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, template-engine, liquid

I'm getting an `Liquid error: undefined method 'to_liquid' for #<Email:0x007f9ca1a62d28>` error on my `Email` object when sending an email using a Liquid template inside a view. However, when I render the view by itself in the browser, it works just fine!

Here's my view:

```
= raw @template.render('email' => @email, 'organization' => @organization)

%p= sanitize("<a href='{{ unsubscribe_url }}''>Click here to unsubscribe</a>")

%p{style:'text-align:center;'}
  Sent with
  = link_to 'Vocalem', 'http://vocalem.com'
```

The relevant parts of my mailer:

```
class BulkMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def bulk_email(recipients, email, organization)
    ...
    @organization = organization
    @email = email
    @template = Liquid::Template.parse(organization.current_email_template.body)
```

Relevant model code:

```
liquid_methods :subject, :body, :id
```

And last but not least, an example of the Liquid giving the error (but working fine in the plain view!):

```
{{email.body}}
```

Oddly, `{{organization.display_name}}` doesn't throw an error, but is just totally blank in the email (despite once again working fine in the plain view).

Any clue what might be going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to create liquid methods using to_liquid in organisation model and check

```
def to_liquid
  {
   'display_name'=>self.name,
   'email_body'=>self.current_email_template.body 
  }
end
```